# executeUpdate with arithmetic operation doesn't change column

Tags: hibernate, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to do a manual order in some app.
The JPAQL to update the fields is something like this:

```
update SortableBean s set s.position = s.position + 1 where s.position >= :initialPosition and s.position < :finalPosition
```

The return of the `executeUpdate` (which as far as I know is the changed rows count) is right, but, neither the `@Version` or the `position` fields are changed.

I've builted a example project and tested it with Hibernate and EclipseLink, both with JPA2, while the original project is in an older Hibernate version. I have the same exception all the  same results all the test cases I can imagine.

My example project spots:

- [Model](https://github.com/caarlos0/persistence-base/blob/sortable-ex/src/test/java/com/github/caarlos0/tests/model/SortableBean.java)
- [DAO](https://github.com/caarlos0/persistence-base/blob/sortable-ex/src/test/java/com/github/caarlos0/tests/dao/SortableDaoImpl.java)
- [The test case for this scenario](https://github.com/caarlos0/persistence-base/blob/sortable-ex/src/test/java/com/github/caarlos0/tests/SortableTests.java)

If you get the code and run the test with `mvn clean install -Dtest=SortableTests`, you will see an output like this:

```
Sortable ID - POS - VERSION
------------------
BEFORE
Sortable 1 - 0 - 1
Sortable 2 - 1 - 1
Sortable 3 - 2 - 1
Sortable 4 - 3 - 1
Sortable 5 - 4 - 1
INITIAL=0 FINAL=3
UPDATED 3 ITEMS
AFTER
Sortable 4 - 0 - 2
Sortable 1 - 0 - 1
Sortable 2 - 1 - 1
Sortable 3 - 2 - 1
Sortable 5 - 4 - 1
```

In other words, looks like it is not updating summing the value, so, I got duplicated positions.

Any thoughts about that?

### EDIT:

The generated SQL seems to be right thought:

```
UPDATE sortables SET version = (version + 1), pos = (pos + 1) WHERE ((pos >= 0) AND (pos < 3))
```

Comment: Try separate your between filter inside parenthesis..: where s.position between :initialPosition and (:finalPosition - 1)

Comment: :finalPosition should be passed with final value, you cannot perform arithmatic operations in the query on the labels

Comment: @CarlosA.Junior parenthesis are implicit in this case, aparently.

Comment: @Zeus changed the query as you said, the bug persists.

Comment: How are you checking that things have changed?  Are you accounting for the fact that JPA has caching in both the EntityManager and allows for a second level cache in the EMF?  You may have to refresh your entity if it was cached prior to your update.  Try calling clear on the em after the change or obtaining a new EntityManager to check the instance values.

Comment: Thanks @Chris! It was it. I didn't knew that find + batch update + find will cause this issue. I cleared the persistence context and it worked. You can see the commit [here](https://github.com/caarlos0/persistence-base/commit/e4d838790c7e39351ce8a22e109a81a4e02dcca7) if you want! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496099/chris) and his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501528/executeupdate-with-arithmetic-operation-doesnt-change-column#comment30648258_20501528), which opens my mind to the real issue.

The issue was that I was doing a batch update, but not clearing the persistence context.

Basically, the fix is [this commit](https://github.com/caarlos0/persistence-base/commit/e4d838790c7e39351ce8a22e109a81a4e02dcca7).

I also had one wrong assertion, but that was the least of my problems.

Thanks everyone!